# COM interop: how to use ICustomMarshaler to call 3rd party component

Tags: c++, marshalling, com-interop

I want to call a method in a COM component from C# using COM interop. This is the methods signature:

```
long GetPrecursorInfoFromScanNum(long nScanNumber,
LPVARIANT pvarPrecursorInfos,
LPLONG pnArraySize)
```

and this is sample code (which I checked is really working) to call it in C++:

```
struct PrecursorInfo
{
    double dIsolationMass;
    double dMonoIsoMass;
    long nChargeState;
    long nScanNumber;
};

void CTestOCXDlg::OnOpenParentScansOcx()
{
    VARIANT vPrecursorInfos;
    VariantInit(&vPrecursorInfos);
    long nPrecursorInfos = 0;

    m_Rawfile.GetPrecursorInfoFromScanNum(m_nScanNumber,
        &vPrecursorInfos,
        &nPrecursorInfos);

    // Access the safearray buffer
    BYTE* pData;
    SafeArrayAccessData(vPrecursorInfos.parray, (void**)&pData);
    for (int i=0; i < nPrecursorInfos; ++i)
    {
        // Copy the scan information from the safearray buffer
        PrecursorInfo info;
        memcpy(&info,
        pData + i * sizeof(MS_PrecursorInfo),
        sizeof(PrecursorInfo));
    }
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(vPrecursorInfos.parray);
}
```

And here's the corresponding C# signature after importing the typelib of the COM component:

```
void GetPrecursorInfoFromScanNum(int nScanNumber, ref object pvarPrecursorInfos, ref int pnArraySize);
```

If I'm not mistaken, I need to pass in null for pvarPrecursorInfos to make COM interop marshal it as the expected VT_EMPTY variant. When I'm doing it, I get a SafeArrayTypeMismatchException - not really surprising, looking at how the result is expected to be handled in the sample. So I was trying to use a custom marshaler. Since a cannot alter the component itself, I tried to introduce it this way:

```
[Guid("06F53853-E43C-4F30-9E5F-D1B3668F0C3C")]
[TypeLibType(4160)]
[ComImport]
public interface IInterfaceNew : IInterfaceOrig 
{
    [DispId(130)]
    int GetPrecursorInfoFromScanNum(int nScanNumber, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(MyMarshaler))] ref object pvarPrecursorInfos, ref int pnArraySize);
}
```

The TypeLibType and DispID attribute are the same as in the original version. This works as far as that the MyMarshaller.GetInstance() method is called, but I do not get a callback in MyMarshaller.NativeToManaged. Instead, an access violation is reported. So is this a reliable approach? If yes - how can I make it work? If no: are there any alternatives?

(Just a footnote: in theory I could try to use managed C++ to call the component natively. However, there are lots of other methods in it that work fine with COM interop, so I would very much like to stick with C# if there is any way.)

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple implementation inheritance, you have to repeat *all* of the IInterfaceOrig members in your new interface declaration.  Looks very painful when it has a dispid of 130.  You'd better try to make the original approach work.  No good reason it should fail, try debugging the COM server code.

Comment: Why multiple inheritance? I am simply extending an existing interface (and only on client side - no changes to the server, I have no access to the server code and have to live with it "as is"). Repeating all the other method declarations in IInterfaceNew isn't nice, but easily done. However, it breaks the other method calls, which worked before. So I am wondering even more if this approach is a hack that's not going to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "the original approach"? Calling the method as it is imported from the typelib gives a SafeArrayTypeMismatchException , and given that I cannot change the server, I do not what I could do to make this work. That's why I was trying to use a custom marshaler.

Comment: COM interfaces just don't behave the same as C# interfaces.  Check this article for reference, the author mistakenly calls it "inheritance tax". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx

Comment: Any progress made here?  I'm trying to access the exact same method from C#

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment earlier. - Yes and no: I found no COM interop solution (and believe there isn't any, the method is just too weird), but managed to call it via managed C++. Leave a comment if you are still interested in the details, I just have no time at the moment.

Comment: Hi Matthias, I would still be interested in a pure c# solution or a 'managed c++' solution for this problem.

Comment: @Matthias I hope you'll notice this request for help :)

Comment: @chhh Sure I did. But with 2 little children and a job it takes some time to dig out the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Vlad, for adding the c++ tag. I didn't know that this affects the rendering of code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since someone asked for it, here's my solution in Managed C++.

```
array<PrecursorInfo^>^ MSFileReaderExt::GetPrecursorInfo(int scanNumber)
{
    VARIANT vPrecursorInfos;
    VariantInit(&vPrecursorInfos);
    long nPrecursorInfos = -1;

    //call the COM component
    long rc = pRawFile->GetPrecursorInfoFromScanNum(scanNumber, &vPrecursorInfos, &nPrecursorInfos);

    //read the result
    //vPrecursorInfos.parray points to a byte sequence
    //that can be seen as array of MS_PrecursorInfo instances
    //(MS_PrecursorInfo is a struct defined within the COM component)
    MS_PrecursorInfo* pPrecursors;
    SafeArrayAccessData(vPrecursorInfos.parray, (void**)&pPrecursors);

    //now transform into a .NET object 
    array<PrecursorInfo^>^ infos = gcnew array<PrecursorInfo^>(nPrecursorInfos);

    MS_PrecursorInfo currentPrecursor;
    for (int i=0; i < nPrecursorInfos; ++i)
    {
        currentPrecursor = pPrecursors[i];

        infos[i] = safe_cast<PrecursorInfo^>(Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(&currentPrecursor), PrecursorInfo::typeid));
    }

    SafeArrayUnaccessData(vPrecursorInfos.parray);

    return infos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Weird, that someone has already -1'd the answer, so my +1 doesn't really help. Should that reside in a separate C++ CLR project?

Comment: @chhh Well, in rep points it's still +8 for me - thank you. But nevertheless: it's exactly because of such unpleasant company that I am generally avoiding to participate actively in SO. - Yes, you need to put it into a separate project. I have a C# facade for the methods I am actually using that delegates either to the COM component directly or to the C++ proxy, depending on the method. Take care of dispatching open, close and the like to both channels if you want to follow this approach.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I've created a managed C++/CLI class that creates an instance of a non-managed COM interface. I save the pointer (non-managed, *) to the interface as a member of the class, while the code is in the constructor, I can do all the library operations (Open, SetCurrentController...), but after the constructor returns, any subsequent call to any method, that uses the COM pointer fails with some AccessViolationException. Would that be possible for you to share more implementation details of this managed/unmanaged interop? Just the basic skeleton of C++ class.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve the issue, however I don't understand what the problem was in the first place. Had to create a completely unmanaged c++ wrapper for the XRawfile2.dll, and then another managed wrapper for unmanaged wrapper, which stored this unamanaged wrapper as a field.. Uhh.. At least in this case my pointers didn't go nuts/null and the thing works for getting something as simple as a precursor scan number. Thanks again, Matthias!

Answer (score 0):

I look at the github code mzLib, which I believe is related to this topic. The code looks good, where it calls

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(path);
```

I think it may cause some problem, better use

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> pathChar = static_cast<wchar_t*>(System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(path).ToPointer());
```

The code then seems to be worked just fine when compiles. However, it might run in problem when imported as dll. I worked on that by adding a constructor,such as

```
public ref class ThermoDLLClass 
{
public:
    ThermoDLLClass();
    PrecursorInfo GetPrecursorInfo(int scanNum, String^ path);


};
```

Then, it seems to get precursorInfo and parameters appropriately.